# Way Out In Space Part 3

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

Lena and Doc climb into a spaceship. Their trajectory can be modeled by the equation $h=-5/7(d+3)(d-45)$  where $h$ is height above the surface, measured in km, and $d$ is horizontal distance from the launching point, also measured in km. An orbiting spacecraft will fly parallel to the surface of the planet, at a constant height of $65$ km the above the surface. At what distance, to the nearest tenth of a kilometer, will Lena and Doc intercept this spacecraft, if at all? Explain your results. (The speed is not a factor in this problem)

I first made $h=-5/7(d+3)(d-45)$ into standard form, so it became $$h=-5/7d^2+30d+96.42857143.$$ I then let $h=65$, so the previous equation became $$65=-5/7d^2+30d+96.42857143\implies -5/7d^2+30d+31.42857143=0$$

I then used the quadratic formula, which yielded
$$d=\frac{-(-30)±\sqrt{30^2-4(-5/7)(31.42857143)}}{2(-5/7)}$$

After doing that I got $d≈43.022$ or $d≈-1.0227$, but since distance can't be negative, the spacecraft and Lena meet at $d=43$.

But I'm not sure if my answer's correct, because I'm wondering if instead of converting the equation into standard form I should have just stuck to the original equation, $h=-5/7(d+3)(d-45)$, and plug $h=65$ into that.

Please let me know which way is correct to find the answer. Thanks.

​
​​ 
​​

Comment: You’ve clearly made an error somewhere along the way. The zeros of the function are at $d=-3$ and $d=45$, and it’s a downward-pointing parabola, so $h$ is negative for $d\lt-3$, making both of your potential solutions implausible. It looks like you went wrong right off the bat when you expanded $-\frac57(d+3)(d-45)$: you only multiplied the first term by $-\frac57$.

Comment: Algebraic errors aside, I have an overall issue with the problem as stated: even if the two trajectories intersect, there’s no mention of the speeds at which the craft are moving, so how do we know that they’ll ever be in the same place at the same time?

Comment: The problem statement does state that speed isn’t a factor in this problem